# how to compute E[X] given X+Y>1, X, Y iid ~ uniform (0, 1)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution

Given $X, Y$ iid $\sim \operatorname{uniform} (0, 1)$

1. one way is $F(x\mid X+Y>1) = P(X<x\mid X+Y>1) = \frac{ P(1-Y<X<x)}{ P(X+Y>1)} = 2 (x-1+y),$  this is incorrect.
2. or, $E[X\mid X+Y>1] = \int_0^1 \int_{1-x}^1 x \,dy \,dx =  \frac{1}{3} $, doesn't look right, since E[X | X+Y>1] should be larger than  $\frac{1}{2}$.
3. Thanks for Henry's comment! This seems right, $$ E[X\mid X+Y>1] = \frac{E[X; X+ Y > 1]}{P(X+Y>1)} =  \frac{\int_0^1 \int_{1-x}^1 x \,dy \,dx}{ P(X+Y > 1) } = \frac{2}{3} $$

And similar way to compute $E[XY]$ given $X + Y > 1$. I think this is resolved.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your equations.

Comment: $P(X \le x \mid X+Y>1)$ should be a function of $x$ but not a function of $y$.  I suspect it is $x^2$ when $x \in [0,1]$

Comment: I suspect you should have tried $E[X \mid X+Y>1] = \dfrac{ \int_0^1 \int_{1-x}^1 x\, dy \,dx}{\int_0^1 \int_{1-x}^1 1\, dy \,dx}$ and similarly $E[XY \mid X+Y>1] = \dfrac{ \int_0^1 \int_{1-x}^1 xy\, dy \,dx}{\int_0^1 \int_{1-x}^1 1\, dy \,dx}$

Comment: Thanks a lot @Henry ! yea your formula makes a lot more sense

Comment: Based on the way you edited this question from the original you should post your solutions as an answer, rather than as an edit to this question.  Especially to keep this site from seeing this question as unanswered.